# Ant to Gradle: JUnit (4.11) Test conversion

Tags: java, gradle, junit, ant, junit4

I'm not very familiar with JUnit, but I'm attempting to translate an ant target that makes use of junit into the gradle equivalent. It's not going so hot, since I'm getting some failures on the gradle side -- I'm under the impression that it's due to inputs not being found somehow/somewhere, but I can't confirm, since it's not readily present in the ant target.

Here's the ant script:

```
<target name="testing">
    <junit printsummary="yes" showoutput="yes">
       <classpath refid="classpath"/>
       <formatter type="xml"/>
       <batchtest fork="yes" todir="someOutputLocation">
          <fileset dir="${base}/testCode">
             <include name="**/included.java"/>
             <exclude name="**/excluded.java"/>
          </fileset>
       </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

And here's (one of the variations) of my gradle attempt:

```
task testing(type:Test){
    useJUnit()
    testClassesDir = file("testCodeCompiled")
    include '**/included.class'
    exclude '**/excluded.class'
    classpath = classpath
}
```

The two errors I get:

```
 junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The AssertionFailedError is supposedly caused by multiple JUnit dependencies, which I don't have. I import a local version of only junit-4.11.

I really don't know why it's not working, though I suspect it's due to some of gradle's complexities. I've seen people mention an ant-junit library, which I may try to use to at least replicate the results from within gradle.

**EDIT:** *A thought occurs: I found JUnit within some of gradle's src files. By calling useJUnit(), I may be using that instead? If so, there could be a double dependency after all?* **Nope.** Got rid of useJUnit() and the local jar separately. The former behaved as it did before whereas the latter exploded.

**MORE INFO: The cause may likely be that the compiledTestCode is missing several of the directories/data that testCode contains. I probably have to copy over the relevant files. Alternatively, is there a way to make gradle's JUnit use .java files instead of .class?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you wondering, the code is fine. I'm just dumb.